# How to write/read into/from file mode ios::binary with derived class?

Tags: c++, serialization

I have 2 classes, Employee and derived classes productEmployee. Here is implement:

class employee:

```
class Employee
{
protected:
    char name[100];
public:
    Employee();//char[100] -> don't declare anything
    virtual ~Employee();//char[100] -> don't delete anything

    virtual float getSalary() = 0;
    virtual void input();//input to name
    virtual void print();//print name
};
```

class productEmployee:

```
class productEmployee :
    public Employee
{
protected:
    int product;
public:
    productEmployee() :Employee(){
        product = 0;
    }
    ~productEmployee();//don't delete anything

    float getLuong() {
        return 150000 * product;
    }
    void input() {
        NhanVien::input();
        cin >> product;
    }
    void print() {
        NhanVien::print();
        cout << "Product: " << product;
        cout << "Salary: " << getSalary() << endl;
    }
};
```

in main.cpp

```
    string file = "data.dat";
    productEmployee a, b;

    a.input();
    ofstream fout(file, ios::binary);
    fout.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));//write object a
    fout.close();

    ifstream fin(file, ios::binary);
    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    fin.read((char*)&b, sizeof(b));//read object a --> b
    fin.close();

    b.print();
```

It work well, I type "12345" and 10. But when I comment from a.input() to fout.close(), mean only this code run(I want to read like that)

```
    string file = "data.dat";
    productEmployee b;
    ifstream fin(file, ios::binary);
    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    fin.read((char*)&b, sizeof(b));//read object a --> b
    fin.close();

    b.print();
```

b.print() only run well NhanVien::print() and count<<product, when into like getSalary(), debug show error:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
```

```
this-> was 0x7FF624BE7290.
```

and I also don't understand meaning address of __vfptr it has values **0x00007ff624be7290{???,???,???,???,???}**

So, how can I read this binary file without write first (code worked well when we write above like cell3 here, but only read like cell4 is not working..)

Comment: The short answer is don't do this, instead properly serialize your data.

Comment: Don't write the vtable to the file and don't attempt to read it back either. You to use logic here that persists only the data, not additional parts of the object...

Comment: The `Employee` class is not trivially-copyable, thus cannot be read or written in this fashion.  [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/rncTe458o).  And I have to ask, since you are one of the many beginners doing this -- who is giving the idea to create binary files?  I see this erroneous coding so many times.   Creating "binary files" requires a lot more thought and planning than simply taking a bunch of bytes and calling `read` and `write`.

Comment: Your design is flawed, it violates seperation of concerns, your class should not be responsible for handling i/o. Make it possible to construct your class from parameters or provide getter/setters and do the file handling in a seperate (source) file. Inheritance should have nothing todo with your io either.

Comment: Reading/writing binary files is not hard, but you cannot just read data into a buffer cast it to an object and think you are done. 1) `new` has never been called so you don't have a valid object and C++ objects can have different memory layout depending on the architecture you run on so saving on one machine and then reading on another can result in complete mismatches.

Comment: You might want to read this page : https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/cpptutorial/

Comment: This approach cannot work. You cannot read or write whole objects containing pointers to a binary file. This includes the pointer that is used to implement virtual functions. It seems to work when you write, but then when you read back the pointer value is meaningless and you get a crash. You need to use a proper serialization technique, either something you invent, or from a third party library.

Comment: In answer below have more information when I tested it, and have more problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem:(Maybe like that)
when I write to object, I don't write virtual table of that, so when I read object from file, this NhanVienSanXuat b don't have virtual table so it had some error, so i only need to use NhanVien *c = b.clone(), c have value we had and also have virtual table, so it works well!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why but this code work:

```
productEmployee temp;
ifstream fin(file, ios::binary); 
fin.read((char*)&temp,sizeof(productEmployee));
fin.close();
cout << temp.getLuong() << endl;

Employee* b;
b = new productEmployee();
*dynamic_cast<productEmployee*>(b) = temp;

cout << b->getLuong() << endl;
```

Especially in line *dynamic_cast<productEmployee*>(b) = temp;
change it into b = &temp or *b =temp it becomes false.

Comment: You may be able to fiddle around and eventually get something that seems to work, but it won't change that what you're trying to do is incorrect.

Comment: thanks, I think I need to come back with write each attribute of this one.

Comment: If you try and create your own serialization format do yourself a favor and write a small header to the files with a version number in it that you can change if the format of one or more of the records changes. That way you can read files in an older format if you need to.